# R : Is it possible to use median and na.rm together in summarise_all?

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, median

I am trying to do 'summarise_all' for all columns using median and want to ignore null data using na.rm = T.

For example,

```
df_sector <- df %>% 
    group_by(Sector) %>% 
    summarise_all(mean, na.rm = T)
```

is working.

However,

```
df_sector <- df %>% 
    group_by(Sector) %>% 
    summarise_all(median, na.rm = T)
```

is not working.

Is there any way to summarise all columns using median and na.rm?

Comment: `summarise_all(median, na.rm = T)` works fine for me (tested with `dplyr_1.0.10`). Maybe share a proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `summarize_all` try `across`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Sector) %>% 
  summarise(across(
    .cols = everything(),
    .fns =  list(mean = ~mean(.,na = TRUE), median = ~median(.,,na = TRUE))))
```